# jQuery Accordion Icons Not Showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've never used the icon feature in jQuery before, but I assumed they would be part of the linked UI style sheet. Do I need to download the icon pack or something before they show up? Here's my project and everything is working, just no icons.

In the Header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

And in the footer:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    var icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };
    jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      icons: icons,
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
      heightStyle: "content"
    });
  });
</script>
```

And the actual html structure of the accordion elements:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Header Text</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Words and stuff</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Oh hello, I'm the second header</h3>
  <div>
    <p>SO MANY WORDS!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yup, if you host the CSS stylesheet you also have to host the image sprite(s). Note that the image sprite(s) need to be in the same position (on the filesystem) relative to the CSS stylesheet as it/they are in the ZIP file you download from the jQuery UI site.

Comment: I'm not hosting them though, I'm using the hosted library and css provided by jQuery.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include some CSS files by the looks of it.

I've created a fiddle with your code, including the CSS file, and everything works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/MaWsm/

`<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't use these icons. I'd just use FontAwesome. I've forked the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PJAwQ/

Comment: I forgot to do a page refresh :))

Comment: Hey, I was just messing around with the FontAwesome features and you can actually make the icon dynamic by putting the class within the jQuery function. fiddle fork here: http://jsfiddle.net/e2h52/2/ Thanks for the great resource!

Comment: In response to what you said on Tasos's answer, you can change WordPress to work with your own jQuery file instead of the built-in one. I use the following code before `wp_head();` in every site I build: `wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/assets/js/jquery.js'); wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); `